# Как получить localStorage из google extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, localstorage

Сделал приложение которое сохраняет параметры в зависимости от localStorage. Пример кода:

```
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Далее я хочу заинжектить скрипт на сайт, и вставить на него значения из localStorage.. Но он его не видит.. Возможно что то нужно сделать чтобы это значение стало глобальным? Подскажите как можно получить на сайте значение из Google extension

Comment: Разве у расширений нет своих, индивидуальных [хранилищ](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)?

Comment: @Other , пробовал. они не срабатывают

Comment: Я создавал расширения и они с успехом использовали хранилища. Что-то у Вас не так было.

Comment: Для каждого домена свой localstorage. Вероятно потому и не получается извлечь данные. А вообще лучше использовать chrome.storage. "пробовал. они не срабатывают" -> покажите как пытались использовать, приведите manifest.json и скрипт где дергался соответствующий функционал